# What might cause an XUnit test to fail in a batch but succeed individually?

Tags: .net, vb.net, xunit

I have the following bracket balancing code written in VB.NET

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Module MatchingBrackets
    Private ReadOnly stack = New Stack(Of Char)
    Private ReadOnly closersOpeners = New Dictionary(Of Char, Char) From {
        {")"c, "("c},
        {"]"c, "["c},
        {"}"c, "{"c}
    }

    Public Function IsPaired(ByVal input As String) As Boolean
        For Each ch In input

            If closersOpeners.ContainsValue(ch) Then
                stack.Push(ch)
            ElseIf closersOpeners.ContainsKey(ch) Then
                If stack.Count > 0 AndAlso stack.Peek() = closersOpeners(ch) Then
                    stack.Pop()
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Dim result = stack.Count = 0
        stack.Clear()
        Return result
    End Function
End Module
```

I'm testing these with the following tests

```
' This file was auto-generated based on version 2.0.0 of the canonical data.
Imports Xunit
Public Class MatchingBracketsTests
    <Fact>
    Public Sub PairedSquareBrackets()
        Dim value = "[]"
        Assert.True(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub EmptyString()
        Dim value = ""
        Assert.True(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub UnpairedBrackets()
        Dim value = "[["
        Assert.False(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub WrongOrderedBrackets()
        Dim value = "}{"
        Assert.False(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub WrongClosingBracket()
        Dim value = "{]"
        Assert.False(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub PairedWithWhitespace()
        Dim value = "{ }"
        Assert.True(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub PartiallyPairedBrackets()
        Dim value = "{[])"
        Assert.False(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub SimpleNestedBrackets()
        Dim value = "{[]}"
        Assert.True(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub SeveralPairedBrackets()
        Dim value = "{}[]"
        Assert.True(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub PairedAndNestedBrackets()
        Dim value = "([{}({}[])])"
        Assert.True(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub UnopenedClosingBrackets()
        Dim value = "{[)][]}"
        Assert.False(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub UnpairedAndNestedBrackets()
        Dim value = "([{])"
        Assert.False(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub PairedAndWrongNestedBrackets()
        Dim value = "[({]})"
        Assert.False(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub PairedAndIncompleteBrackets()
        Dim value = "{}["
        Assert.False(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub TooManyClosingBrackets()
        Dim value = "[]]"
        Assert.False(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub MathExpression()
        Dim value = "(((185 + 223.85) * 15) - 543)/2"
        Assert.True(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
    <Fact>
    Public Sub ComplexLatexExpression()
        Dim value = "\left(\begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{3} & x\\ \mathrm{e}^{x} &... x^2 \end{array}\right)"
        Assert.True(IsPaired(value))
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run them *en masse* in Visual Studio or via `dotnet test`, three fail, viz

```
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  MatchingBrackets -> D:\my_csharp\matching-brackets\bin\Debug\net5.0\MatchingBrackets.dll
Test run for D:\my_csharp\matching-brackets\bin\Debug\net5.0\MatchingBrackets.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.10.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
  Failed MatchingBrackets.MatchingBracketsTests.SimpleNestedBrackets [2 ms]
  Error Message:
   Assert.True() Failure
Expected: True
Actual:   False
  Stack Trace:
     at MatchingBrackets.MatchingBracketsTests.SimpleNestedBrackets() in D:\my_csharp\matching-brackets\MatchingBracketsTests.vb:line 42
  Failed MatchingBrackets.MatchingBracketsTests.PairedAndNestedBrackets [< 1 ms]
  Error Message:
   Assert.True() Failure
Expected: True
Actual:   False
  Stack Trace:
     at MatchingBrackets.MatchingBracketsTests.PairedAndNestedBrackets() in D:\my_csharp\matching-brackets\MatchingBracketsTests.vb:line 52
  Failed MatchingBrackets.MatchingBracketsTests.PairedWithWhitespace [< 1 ms]
  Error Message:
   Assert.True() Failure
Expected: True
Actual:   False
  Stack Trace:
     at MatchingBrackets.MatchingBracketsTests.PairedWithWhitespace() in D:\my_csharp\matching-brackets\MatchingBracketsTests.vb:line 32

Failed!  - Failed:     3, Passed:    14, Skipped:     0, Total:    17, Duration: 81 ms - MatchingBrackets.dll (net5.0)
```

However, if I run each of those failed tests individually, they don't fail.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That usually happens if the tests or what is being tested shares a common resource that is being manipulated by each test affecting the test case of another test that is being exercised simultaneously.

In this particular case the `Stack` is the shared resource among all those tests.

Every time the function is called is clears the stack which would affect any other call to the function that has not completed as yet.

If you refactor to have the stack as local variable, I believe that should isolation the function.

```
Public Module MatchingBrackets        
    Private ReadOnly closersOpeners = New Dictionary(Of Char, Char) From {
        {")"c, "("c},
        {"]"c, "["c},
        {"}"c, "{"c}
    }

    Public Function IsPaired(ByVal input As String) As Boolean
        Dim stack = New Stack(Of Char)
        For Each ch In input    
            If closersOpeners.ContainsValue(ch) Then
                stack.Push(ch)
            ElseIf closersOpeners.ContainsKey(ch) Then
                If stack.Count > 0 AndAlso stack.Peek() = closersOpeners(ch) Then
                    stack.Pop()
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Dim result = stack.Count = 0
        stack.Clear()
        Return result
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Marvellous. Thank you very much indeed.